# How to start a screen with crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron, python, raspberry-pi, gnu-screen

**sudo Crontab -e**

```
15 0 * * 1-5 /usr/bin/screen -S wake_up -d -m /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py
```

*But at 00:15 there is no screen started...*

*This command: (worked in terminal)*

**screen -S wake_up -d -m /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py**

Python File:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
x = 1
while x<10:
  print (x)
  x += 1
  time.sleep(1)
```

**/var/log/syslog**

```
Nov 17 00:15:01 pi cron[352]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Nov 17 00:15:01 pi CRON[32392]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/screen -S wake_up -d -m /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py)
```

I even got the log its started correct

Comment: I have the Raspberry Pi OS
Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
screen -S wake_up -d -m  /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py
```

This will not keep a command screen open. Instead create this file:

```
% cat /home/pi/auto/.boot-screenrc
screen -t cpu 1
stuff /home/pi/auto/wake_up.py\015
```

This starts a screen, inserts (stuffs) the python command into the stdin, and adds a return.

Then add:

```
screen -d -m -S wake_up -c /home/pi/auto/.boot-screenrc
```

Also keep in mind, cron's default PATH is very abbreviated. If you have 3rd party software loaded, it is likely not in the path. Make sure to use absolute paths instead of the env command. Alternatively you can add a line at the top of your crontab file like:

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/some/other/path
```

Comment: Okay thank you sm

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Remove `sudo` so that you're editing your own `crontab` rather than root's. And there's no need to specify `/usr/bin/screen`; you can use `screen`.

The `screen` session will exist for the duration of your `python` program. When the program exits so will `screen`.